# Web API for uploading multiple images with android multi part data

Tags: java, android, asp.net, api

How can we read image byte array in the web api Controller along with  string value and compress the image size..

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... URL) {
        try {
            String url = "http://x.x.x.xxx:x/hhservice/api/BookingRequest/PostBookingRequest";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            if (userimage_byteArray != null) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Applyonline3.this, "Applicant Image is not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (idimage_byteArray != null) {
                mpEntity.addPart("ID_IMAGE", new ByteArrayBody(idimage_byteArray, "image/jpeg", "test2.jpg"));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Applyonline3.this, "Id Image is not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (appplicant_visit_status.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) { Toast.makeText(Applyonline3.this, "Payslip Image is not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            mpEntity.addPart("booking_request_value", new StringBody(jsonobjstr, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            post.setEntity(mpEntity);
            HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
            String Response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            RESPONSE_LENGTH_CODE = Response.length();
            Log.d("Response:", Response);}
```

Comment: anyone have idea about this please help me

Comment: what you mean by `"along with json string"`?